# CircleIndicator to show page number in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am creating an Activity that uses ViewPager to show a set of fragments as a slideshow. To indicate which page to show I am using : https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

This is the XML for the activity :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/introduction_view_pager"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/skip_to_login"
    android:onClick="skipToLogin"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the .java file for the activity :

```
public class IntroductionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

static final int NO_OF_SLIDES = 4;
ViewPager mViewPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
Button mButton;
CircleIndicator mCircleIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduction);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    mCircleIndicator = (CircleIndicator)findViewById(R.id.circle_indicator);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.introduction_view_pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new SlideScreenPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mCircleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
public class SlideScreenPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public SlideScreenPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0 : return new IntroductionViewPagerFragmentOne();
            case 1 : return new IntroductionViewPagerFragmentTwo();
            case 2 : return new IntroductionViewPagerFragmentThree();
            case 3 : return new IntroductionViewPagerFragmentFour();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NO_OF_SLIDES;
    }
}
}
```

The fragments work perfectly, but the CircleIndicator does not show. How do i get the CircleIndicator?

Answer (score 0):

Use this gradle dependency

```
'com.viewpagerindicator:parent:2.4.1'
```

Comment: Does not work!! Does not identify if I'm trying to add the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code snippet below in your file (I've used the same circle indicator and it works like charm).

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        circleIndicator.onPageSelected(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
```

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/introduction_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="skipToLogin"
        android:text="login" />

</LinearLayout>
```